# Do I need to step up to Apple Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to distribute beta version of my app to 100+ beta testers, I got only their e-mails without UDID.
Do I need to step up to Enterprise Program or just base developer program and test flight is enough?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ "You can invite up to 10,000 testers". Will you have more or less than 10,000 testers?

Comment: @Fogmeister No, around 200. Do I need their UDID? Or email is enough?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/testflight/ "You can invite up to 10,000 testers using just their email address or by sharing a public link." Did you click on the link and read the first paragraph?

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, but the thing is I can't see any option to add external testers, only internal so I thought it is available in Enterprise. Maybe it will enable when I upload build?

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question. If you haven't uploaded an app yet... try it. It doesn't cost you anything to create an app and upload a build. You will see a TestFlight tab in there. The page I linked above has ALL the information you could need about how to add testflight users to your app. 

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Cheers

Comment: From the page I linked above... "For step-by-step instructions on creating groups, inviting testers, and adding builds in TestFlight, read App Store Connect Help."

Comment: You only have to sign up into Enterprise program if you company intent to **not distribute** app at AppStore, but for a internal members of a company. In other words, enterprise program is a way to distribute production grade apps for internal usage, not for public in general. In your case you just need to register people allowed to test at TestFlight tab of your app at Apple Connect site. As mentioned before, you have 10k slots available for beta testers.